# Remove timestamp and url from string python

Tags: string, python-3.x, timestamp, data-cleaning

I have a string from which I have to remove the timestamp and punctuation. And I have to remove all the digits also but responseCode value
has to be kept as is for example 400 in this case. And wherever 400 comes, it should not be removed. And I want to remove all the url's
and file name ending with tar.gz.

```
mystr="sun aug 19 13:02:09 2018 I_am.98189:  hello please connect to the local host:8080 
sun aug 19 13:02:10 2018 hey.94289:  hello not able to find the file 
sun aug 19 13:02:10 2018 I_am.94289: Base url for file_transfer is: abc/vd/filename.tar.gz 
mon aug 19 13:02:10 2018 how_94289: $var1={ 
  'responseCode' = '400', 
  'responseDate' = 'Sun, 19 Aug 2018 13:02:08 ET', 
  'responseContent' = 'ABC'  }
mon aug 20 13:02:10 2018 hello!94289: Error performing action, failed with error code [400]
"
```

Expected result:

```
"I_am hello please connect to the local host 
hello not able to find the file 
Base url for file_transfer 
var1 
  responseCode = 400 
  responseDate  
  responseContent = ABC 
Error performing action, failed with error code 400
"
```

My Solution to remove punctuation:

```
punctuations = '''!=()-[]{};:'"\,<>.?@#$%^&*_~'''
no_punct = ""
for char in mystr:
   if char not in punctuations:
       no_punct = no_punct + char

# display the unpunctuated string
print(no_punct)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe:

```
patterns = [r"\w{3} \w{3} \d{2} \d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2} \d{4}\s*",    #sun aug 19 13:02:10 2018
        r"\w{3}, \d{2} \w{3} \d{4} \d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2} \w{2}\s*", #Sun, 19 Aug 2018 13:02:08 ET
        r":\s*([\da-zA_Z]+\/)+([a-zA-Z0-9\.]+)",                #URL
        r"([a-zA-Z_!]+)[\.!_]\d+:\s*",                          #word[._!]number:>=0space
        r":\d+",
        "[/':,${}\[\]]"                                         #punctuations
        ]

s = mystr

for p in patterns:
    s = re.sub(p,'', s)

s = s.strip()

print(s)
```

Output:

```
hello please connect to the local host
hello not able to find the file
Base url for file_transfer is
var1= 
  responseCode = 400 
  responseDate =  
  responseContent = ABC  
Error performing action failed with error code 400
```

Comment: Hi, I have updated question. 98189 is not always after I_am. Can you please edit your answer?